# fish shell: Prompt changing to '>'

Tags: fish

I recently switched to fish and modified one of the prompts available from `fish_config` to look like this.

```
function fish_greeting
    fortune
end

function fish_prompt

    echo

    set -l retc brblack
    test $status = 0; and set retc bryellow

    set -q __fish_git_prompt_showupstream
    or set -g __fish_git_prompt_showupstream auto

    function _nim_prompt_wrapper
        set retc $argv[1]
        set cust $argv[4]
        set field_name $argv[2]
        set field_value $argv[3]

        set_color normal
        set_color $retc
        echo
        echo -n ' ├─'
        echo -n '[ '

        set_color normal
        test -n $field_name
        and echo -n $field_name

        set_color -o brblack
        echo -n ' ▶ '

        set_color $retc
        set_color $cust
        echo -n $field_value

        set_color $retc
        echo -n ' ]'
    end

    set_color $retc
    echo -n '─┬─'
    echo -n '[ '

    set_color -o red
    echo -n (prompt_hostname)
    echo -n ': '

    if test "$USER" = root -o "$USER" = toor
        set_color -o brred
    else
        set_color -o brwhite
    end
    echo -n $USER

    set_color -o brblack
    echo -n ' ▶ '

    set_color -o brcyan
    echo -n (pwd)

    set_color $retc
    echo -n ' ]'

    # Virtual Environment
    set -q VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT
    or set -g VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT true
    set -q VIRTUAL_ENV
    and _nim_prompt_wrapper $retc ' ' (basename "$VIRTUAL_ENV") cyan

    # git
    set prompt_git (fish_git_prompt | string trim -c ' ()')
    test -n "$prompt_git"
    and _nim_prompt_wrapper $retc (basename -s .git (git config --get remote.origin.url) 2> /dev/null) $prompt_git

    # New line
    echo

    # Background jobs
    set_color normal
    for job in (jobs)
        set_color $retc
        echo -n ' │ '
        set_color brown
        echo $job
    end
    set_color normal
    set_color $retc
    echo -n ' ╰─> '
    set_color normal
end
```

The general layout of my prompt:

```
─┬─[ hostname: user ▶ pwd ]
 ╰─> _
```

And blow is what I want **instead** of `>`:

```
─┬─[ hostname: user ]
 ├─[ pwd ]
 ╰─> _
```

OR

```
─┬─[ hostname: username ]
 ├─⎡ as_much_as_possible ⎤
 ├─⎣ the_rest_of_PWD     ⎦
 ╰─> _
```

But, when `$PWD` is longer than the window's column size, the whole prompt is just `>`. I feel that using `$COLUMNS` should work, but I don't know how I can check the length of `pwd` before echoing it.

I DO NOT WANT TO USE `prompt_pwd`.

Thanks in advance! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store whatever you want in a variable and then check it, modify it however you want and then echo it.

Here's a rough sketch:

```
set -l firstline '─┬─[' (prompt_hostname): $USER ▶ $PWD ']'
set -l secondline
if test (string length -- "$firstline") -gt $COLUMNS
     # move $PWD to the second line
     set firstline '─┬─[' (prompt_hostname): $USER ']'
     set secondline '├─[' $PWD ']'
end
echo $firstline
echo $secondline
```

> I DO NOT WANT TO USE prompt_pwd.

You very possibly do. It handles replacing $HOME with `~` (which saves quite a few columns) and does shortening to $fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length characters, or no shortening other than `~` if that's set to 0.

You can even adapt the shortening to $COLUMNS. From my prompt:

```
# Shorten pwd if prompt is too long
set -l pwd (prompt_pwd)
# 0 means unshortened
for i in $fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length 0 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
    set pwd (fish_prompt_pwd_dir_length=$i prompt_pwd)
    set -l len (string length -- $prompt_host_nocolor$pwd$last_status$delim' ')
    if test $len -lt $COLUMNS
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: I had no idea fish could do `var=value cmd ...`. I see [from the docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#overriding-variables-for-a-single-command) this was recently introduced in version 3.1

Comment: Is there a way to apped the output of echo in a variable?

Comment: `set var $firstline $secondline` will have the lines as separate elements in a list, so `printf %s\n $var` will later output it. If $var is already set, `set var $var $nextline` or `set -a var $nextline` will add $nextline to it. Using `echo` isn't needed or helpful here.